# Error while passing input parameters to stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have written a stored procedure where i only give input parameters to insert records in to four tables but i am not able to find why its throwing below error, though i am passing correct number .any suggestions

also, purchase table is referencing foreign key of EID from employees table and purchase table is referencing foreign key of PID from products table
ans purchase table is referencing foreign key of CID from customers table ,
and after i pass parameters to stored procedure ,while insertion i want to give input via keyboard...

stored procedure as follows:

```
 PROCEDURE add_purchase(e_id IN char,p_id IN char,
 c_id IN char,pur_qty IN NUMBER) AS
   Total_Price NUMBER(7,2);
   ENAME VARCHAR2(15 BYTE);
   TELEPHONE# CHAR(12 BYTE);
   CNAME VARCHAR2(15 BYTE);       
   VISITS_MADE NUMBER(4,0);
   PNAME VARCHAR2(15 BYTE);
   QOH NUMBER(5,0);
   QOH_THRESHOLD NUMBER(4,0);
   ORIGINAL_PRICE NUMBER(6,2);
   DISCNT_RATE NUMBER(3,2);       
BEGIN    

  INSERT INTO employees (EID,ENAME,TELEPHONE#) 
  values (e_id,'&ENAME','&TELEPHONE');

  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS    (CID,CNAME,TELEPHONE#,VISITS_MADE,LAST_VISIT_DATE) 
  VALUES (c_id,'&CNAME','&TELEPHONE','&VISITS_MADE',SYSDATE);

  INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PID,PNAME,QOH,QOH_THRESHOLD,ORIGINAL_PRICE,DISCNT_RATE) 
  VALUES (p_id,'&PNAME','&QOH','&QOH_THRESHOLD','&ORIGINAL_PRICE','&DISCNT_RATE'); 


 select (pro.ORIGINAL_PRICE * (1 - pro.DISCNT_RATE)) into Total_Price
 from purchases pur,products pro where pro.pid=pur.pid; 

 INSERT INTO purchases(EID,PID,CID,QTY,PTIME,Total_Price)VALUES
(e_id,p_id,c_id,pur_qty,sysdate,Total_Price);   

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  raise;
END add_purchase;
```

execution :

```
  EXEC add_purchase ('e11','p011','c011',100);
```

error :

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 1
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: could it be that e_id in the first insert's values clause is expected to be a number? I don't recall any automatic promotion from char to int or to number in sql. It has been ages since I used it, but oracle used to be very clear in docs about what each ora-#### number means.

Comment: @joshp : e_id,p_id,c_id are all char types

Comment: You think the '&ORIGINAL_PRICE' will work in a stored procedure? I see it as a SQLPlus substitution variable that won't work in a stored procedure, but only in a batch with accept statements. I don't have oracle around to try it, (tutorialspoint?), but is '&ORIGINAL_PRICE' really a valid NUMBER(6,2)? Doesn't look that way to me. First thing I would try is take those substitutions out of the sp and put them in the script you run to call the sp. But maybe I miss the point. This is about 20 years old for me.

Answer (score 0):

An ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be

With keyboard input the original price, discount rate, visits made values might cause this error when input is not actually a number.

**But do stored procedures even allow keyboard input?** Last time I checked they don't.

So this insert is apparently passing a literal string '&ORIGINAL_PRICE' where a NUMBER is expected.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PID,PNAME,QOH,QOH_THRESHOLD,ORIGINAL_PRICE,DISCNT_RATE) 
  VALUES (p_id,'&PNAME','&QOH','&QOH_THRESHOLD','&ORIGINAL_PRICE','&DISCNT_RATE');
```

It seems that strings like '&ORIGINAL_PRICE' should always produce this sort of error when trying to convert to NUMBER,

So instead of referring to substitutions like '&ORIGINAL_PRICE' in the sp's insert values clause, for each substitution you would do something like...

```
accept o_price number format '99999.99' prompt 'Original Price:'
```

In the script that calls the sp, then call the sp passing &o_price as a parameter.

The the insert values clause in the sp would look like

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PID,PNAME,QOH,QOH_THRESHOLD,ORIGINAL_PRICE,DISCNT_RATE) 
  VALUES (p_id,PNAME,QOH,QOH_THRESHOLD,ORIGINAL_PRICE,DISCNT_RATE);
```

There would be no more & substitutions inside the sp's code.

ORIGINAL_PRICE and the other input parameters are already declared with the correct types. So you would then likely only get a conversion error if you type in bad input.

If columns such as ORIGINAL_PRICE are actually defined as character in the table then the problem might come in the expression `(1 - pro.DISCNT_RATE)`.

So I think someone can give you a better answer, but I post mine as possibly useful.